# calculate date and show result in different intervals

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is a datetime field and and want to calculate the day difference. In the next step I want to have different columns for different time intervals with 0 or 1.

The structure of base table is name and date.

The Output should look like this:

```
name|date                   |days|interval 0-31 |interval 31-60|
Tim |2014-12-07 08:04:25.000|1   |1             |0             |
Tom |2014-10-28 08:04:25.000|42  |0             |1             |
```

Thx in advance for your help!

Comment: Output is good, but if we dont know what the table structure is to start with, we cant give you the stuff in the middle.  Please post an example table, or a [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)

Comment: How does `2014-10-28 08:04:25.000` relate to `42` days?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this then:

```
SELECT        StartDate, DayCount, CASE WHEN DayCount > 0 AND DayCount < 31 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS  daysZeroTo31,
  CASE WHEN DayCount > 31 AND DayCount < 60 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS days31to60
FROM            (SELECT        StartDate, EndDate, DATEDIFF(dy, StartDate, EndDate) AS DayCount
  FROM            YourTable) AS sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to count records that fall into specified intervals, something like this would work.  Just repeat the SUM(Case... line for each interval modifying the range check.

```
SELECT        
   SUM(CASE WHEN DayCount > 0 AND DayCount < 31 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ZeroTo31
FROM            
  (SELECT        
       DATEDIFF(dy, StartDate, EndDate) AS DayCount
    FROM YourTable) AS sub
```

Comment: I don't want to sum. Calculated columns should only show the interval with o or 1